# How to call a method of another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to call the method `mymethod` of class b, using the method `currentMethod` of class a. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
@interface B : NSObject
- (void) myMethod;
@end
@implementation B
- (void) myMethod {
    ... do something ...
}
@end
```

Then you could do:

```
@implementation A
- (void) currentMethod {
   [[[B new] autorelease] myMethod];
}
@end
```

Of course, that is exceedingly unlikely to do what you want.  In particular, that would cause a new instance of `B` to be instantiated on each call to `currentMethod`.   I would bet that your question is more along the lines of *"I have an instance of Object A and an instance of Object B from somewhere else in my program, how do I message B from A?"*

Ultimately, you should read the [Objective-C programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) to understand how classes and instances work.   From there, you will need to understand how [iPhone applications are architected](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to understand where your various instances go and how they get a hold of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to :

1/ Put the method you want to call in the interface
@interface B

-(void)methodB;

2/ You have a reference to the object that you want to call the method. Like initWithModel:

@interface A

B _b;

implementation A

initWithB:(B b)

_b = b;

[_b methodB];